# iMac White screen, no chime, keyboard not connected

Tags: mac, imac, white-screen

I had upgraded my iMac Late 2012 to SSD - Toshiba TR200.

With a Windows installation usb I had to format the drive first then with macOS boot usb I had installed High Sierra by choosing APFS file format.

I worked fine, opened normally, restarted normally, I had browsed internet etc no problems.

Then I had to reinstall High Sierra with a bootable usb for some reason ( i wish i had not).

On boot screen, instead of usb drive, I mistakenly selected third item, i do not remember its name. First was my harddrive, second was usb drive that should have been selected.

Now it stucks at white screen. No chime on startup. I hear fans. I wanted to try some startup key options but I think my bluetooth keyboard is not connected, because caps lock light does not work.

As a last try I have reopened and put my old HDD but it is same.

I would be glad if you could share any suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Test with a USB keyboard, Cmd/R or Cmd/Shift/R for Recovery, D or Opt/D for AHT; but no chimes is ominous....

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the keyboard combinations (Shift, Command, Command+R,Alt), SMC reset but still same.

Comment: By the way I have just noticed that while in white screen with wired usb keyboard connected, caps lock light is not working.

So does it mean my imac does not recognize wired usb?

I know it is working by testing on my laptop. It is Microsoft's wired usb keyboard.